How to use tutorial dialogs in Android
In my application I want show some tutorial for users about menus, buttons and more...
I want create view such as Showcase , Tooltip for show this help. 
I want this tutorial mode support Skip, Next and Previous button. 
I searched many times in AndroidArsenal , Android365 site about Showcase or tootlip but unfortunately I can't find any thing same the my UI :(
Can you suggest to me similar library ?
Thank you <3

This feature is called a coachmark.
You can take a look at already existing libraries like
Reveal
Or
Coachmark
If you're still using XML you can try and adapt accordingly
Showcase View

Thank you, but I used XML and I want add custom dialog style such as above image. how can I it?
